# Send two or more Recipient using api and php code

Tags: php, html

I want is to send it by two or group and  doesn't need to type the number of my recipient. please help.

```
<?php
if ($_POST) {
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $msg = $_POST['msg'];

    //this is my free api code to send message .
    $api = "TR-ROSEM239665_1R9EJ";
    $text = $name . ":" . $msg;

    //This is my api code here .
    $result = itexmo($number, $text, $api);
    if ($result == "") {
        echo "iTexMo: No response from server!!!
        Please check the METHOD used (CURL or CURL-LESS). If you are using CURL 
       then try CURL-LESS and vice versa.   
        Please CONTACT US for help. ";
    } else if ($result == 0) {
        echo "Message Sent!";
    } else {
        echo "Error Num " . $result . " was encountered!";
    }
}
?>

<form method="POST" align='center' action="offering2.php">
    <table border="5" cellpadding="2" align="center" style="width:170%">


        <th><label for="name" size="12">Your Name</label></th>
        <td><input type="text" maxlength="10" class="form-control" id="name" 
                   placeholder="name" name="name" value="OSCA OFFICE" required></td><tr>
            <th><label for="number">Recipient Number</label></th>

            i can only send one recipient. 

            <td><input type="text" maxlength="11" class="form-control" id="number" 
                       placeholder="number" name="number" required></td><tr>
            <th><label for="msg">Your Message</label></th>
            <td><textarea rows="12" cols="99" name="msg" placeholder="message here" 
                          onkeyup="countChar(this)" required></textarea></td><tr>

        <h2 align="center" class="text-right" id="charNum">99</h2>
        <td></td>
        <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">SEND</button></td>
```

Comment: As i understand your Topic no clear for me, you want more "recipient" and you use input to add only one value, so change the input and add multi choice elements as checkbox, also your $_POST['name'] is going to be an Array and you have to declare in the input type="checkbox" the same name="name[]" as attributes, this give you from php a array so more "recipient" and you can access to them with a loop or $_POST['name'][0] with indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use isset function

```
<button type="submit" name="submit">send</button>


<?php
if (isset($_POST('submit'))) {
$number = $_POST['number'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$msg = $_POST['msg'];

//this is my free api code to send message .
$api = "TR-ROSEM239665_1R9EJ";
$text = $name . ":" . $msg;

//This is my api code here .
$result = itexmo($number, $text, $api);
if ($result == "") {
    echo "iTexMo: No response from server!!!
    Please check the METHOD used (CURL or CURL-LESS). If you are using CURL 
   then try CURL-LESS and vice versa.   
    Please CONTACT US for help. ";
} else if ($result == 0) {
    echo "Message Sent!";
} else {
    echo "Error Num " . $result . " was encountered!";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of a function call (you can 
    use "null !== func()" instead) in 
    C:\xampp\htdocs\SeniorSystem\cman\admin\offering2.php on line 49  error message found..

Comment: if you want to send it by two or more group so just go to reference https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp but it work on live not on localhost.